# AngularJs Directive not found

Tags: angularjs

Here im trying to Binding directive but why i'm getting error  during the Binding

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="User.Password" name="psw" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="User.conPassword" name="cpsw"  
       data-apple-psw="User.Password" required />
```

**crl.Js**

```
app.directive('applePsw', function () {
return {
    require: " ngModel",
    scope: {
        //passwordVerify: "="
        applePsw: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
```

Comment: what is the error and please post your full code of directive

Comment: data-apple-psw="User.Password"   when i mention  "applePsw" i'm getting Error

Comment: post entire code bro and if possible try to create a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: You have a typo in require property, remove first space char.

Comment: 1. use single quotes instead of double quotes 2. remove the space in `" ngModel"`(it should be `'ngModel'`)